# If I have a page that gets a lot of StumbleUpon traffic, will that traffic fall if I move it?

Tags: traffic, redirects

Say I have a [page](http://artlung.com/smorgasborg/how_to_tick_people_off.shtml) that gets a lot of traffic via [StumbleUpon](http://www.stumbleupon.com/). It's an ancient page, and I might want to move it to another site as part reorganizing my old site. I intend to keep the content identical, other than maybe a slim header or footer.

If I put in a `permanent 301` redirect, will my page be penalized by StumbleUpon or other social bookmarking sites? Will I lose the existing traffic?

Comment: To bravely go where no redirect has gone before .. +1 :)

Comment: I couldn't find anything about StumbleUpon's handling of 301s either. You should set up the redirect and track its progress on another page you've submitted to StumbleUpon.

Comment: It's funny, I never submitted that page in particular to StumbleUpon, it just seemed sucked into SU sometime maybe 7 years ago. Trying it with a lower trafficked page is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it looks to me, based on [this question](http://getsatisfaction.com/stumbleupon/topics/need_help_on_updating_the_web_site_url) over on StumbleUpon's support site that there's a bit of a downside in terms of one aspect of SU, from a SU employee:

> Sorry, we can't redirect existing
>   reviews to new urls, nor change the
>   entry details for existing reviews.
>
> You may wish to ensure that you have a
>   redirect on each of your "old" pages
>   that have been reviewed, so that any
>   visitors following that route end up
>   at your new content.

So basically changing the URL will disassociate the existing reviews and stumble data from the page. Now, users can still get there (assuming the redirects are done properly on the server), but there is a downside.

But based on what I see of some sites that implement redirects, there *should* be no downside from changing the url. Still, I think I'm planning to not play with this for existing pages with high traffic.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know a ton about StumbleUpon but I do know that Google only gives you a slight ding for 301 redirects.  So by that measure you should not have an issue with doing a 301 redirect for a page that StumbleUpon is linked to.  Google will still crawl it and just see it is now a 301.

The only concern I would have is if StumbleUpon removes links that it finds to be 301 redirects. I could not find anything from StumbleUpon that would make me think that they do that.